# Is it safe to join two arrays with for loop and findIndex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint

I have the following code that will join two arrays by comparing the id property of each element.

```js
//dummy test data
var arrayA = [{
    id: 0,
    data: "hello"
}, {
    id: 1,
    data: "world"
}, {
    id: 2,
    data: "!"
}],
arrayB = [{
    id: 2,
    data2: "bbb"
}, {
    id: 1,
    data2: "aaa"
}, {
    id: 3,
    data2: "ccc"
}];

(function(a, b) {
    for (var i in a) {
        var pos = b.findIndex(function(obj) {
            return a[i].id == obj.id;
        });
        if (pos !== -1) {
            a[i] = $.extend({}, a[i], b[pos]);
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    }
})(arrayA, arrayB);

console.log(arrayA);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, when tested in Chrome dev tools, the code works perfectly fine. However, ESLint keeps telling me that function in a loop can lead to wrong output ([no-loop-func](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func)). So, the question is, is it safe to use the loop variable in the anonymous function inside [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) or [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)? If not, under what circumstance could the code go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it safe to use the loop variable in the anonymous function inside `Array.prototype.findIndex()` or `find()`? If not, under what circumstance could the code go wrong?

Yes, it is safe and this is because the callback passed to `findIndex` is executed synchronously (the same is true for `find`). The lint rule makes sense since in the general case a callback function passed to some method *could* be called asynchronously, in which case it *is* a problem. That problem could then be resolved by declaring `i` with block scope:

```
for (let i in a) {
```

This change may even silence the linter for your case.

#### Remarks

Note that you can do the job without having to scan the `b` array with `findIndex` (or `find`) in every iteration, and so make this run with *O(n)* instead of *O(n²)* time complexity, if you would use a Map of some sort.

Also, it is generally [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) to iterate over an array with the `for...in` syntax. In your case you could use the `forEach` array method.

Here is how that could look with some ES6 code:

```
(function(a, b) {
    const b_ids = new Map(b.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]));
    a.forEach( (obj, i) => {
        if (b_ids.has(obj.id)) {
            a[i] = Object.assign({}, obj, b_ids.get(obj.id));
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    });
})(arrayA, arrayB);
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what the issue is?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your code is still O(n²), as the new Map needs to be searched. Also it is not recommended to allocate unnecessary memory in such a simple case. You've just created a new Map object with the size of `b` array, two new functions and a lot of arrays (when creating Map). This is abuse of the garbage collector and JIT compiler for sure.

Comment: @HankMoody, The search in a Map is not *O(n)*, but *O(1)*. For performance reasons the use of the Map is certainly the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is explained in the [article](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func) you've mentioned. In short: it is safe in your case, but may not become safe if you later modify that code.

I would suggest to rewrite your code into two loops, as it is easier to understand, safer and more performant.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var found = false;

    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) 
        if (a[i].id === b[j].id) {
            Object.assign(a[i], b[j]);
            found = true;
            break;
        }

    if (!found)
        ...
 }
```

Alternate method without the `found` variable (which to me is kind of hacky):

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) 
        if (a[i].id === b[j].id)
            break;

    if (j < b.length) {
        // Found a match
        Object.assign(a[i], b[j]);
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Simplicity of the code is important and nested functions in loops usually tend to be less perfromant, readable and confusing (for others or for you after some time).

Comment: The problem with two loops is that, when you want to execute something when no match is found, as seen in the updated question, you need an additional boolean variable (and reduced readability), whereas with Array.prototype.find() you only need an else branch. But of course, yours does not break no-loop-func. That's why I'm asking here if it's safe.

Comment: You still need the `pos` variable, which indicates if result was found, so it is like the boolean variable.

Comment: I've added an alternate implementation with less variables.